# Как перенести курсор в C#

Tags: c#, консоль

Надо вывести бинарное дерево в консоль. Хотел бы его нарисовать так, чтобы корень был на первой строке посередине, его дети делил вторую строку на 3 равные части и так далее. В Паскале есть функция, переводящая курсор на позицию (x,y). А в С# есть что-то подобное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[System.Console.SetCursorPosition()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx)